# What is the right article in self-description?

Tags: articles

If I want to introduce myself to people who don't know me at all, which article should I be using or none? Example:

John Doe - The Passionate Entrepreneur OR
John Doe - A Passionate Entrepreneur OR
John Doe - Passionate Entrepreneur

Comment: In this context, I'd use **a**

Comment: They are all usable. It depends on whether you want to imply that you are the only entrepreneur with passion, or whether you are just one of many. I'd choose the last example (if at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "The Passionate Entrepreneur" to be some kind of official *title* for what you do or the name of your business (as you've indicated by capitalizing the name) then *the* is correct.  However if you just want to tell people that you have passion for entrepreneurship, then you would say *a* (and not capitalize the name).

For example, suppose I am an adventurous and bold diner and try unusual food.  I could tell people I'm ***an*** intrepid gourmet.  But if I want to start a food blog with that name either as a business or a hobby, I would call it ***The*** Intrepid Gourmet.

You can also say *John Doe -- Passionate Entrepreneur* **if** you want to be dramatic, since that sounds like a film or book title.